# Confirmation of git push command

Tags: git, git-push

How I can configure some confirmation on git push command in concrete branch? I have production branch and sometimes I forgot that I in production branch and push not those changes.

Answer (score 5):

One potential solution would be to remove the config associated with 'production' branch.

```
git config --unset branch.<branch>.remote
git config --unset branch.<branch>.merge
```

That way, you *have* to mention to what remote you want to pull from (or push to, for that matter).
If you define an alias for the pull which:

- pull
- and then remove the remote and merge config for that branch,

you are sure you will not be able, for that branch, to do a simple "git pull" without entering additional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the pre-push hook for the commits into protected branches like "master".

Git offers a number of hooks for various actions ([as written in the documention](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)). The hooks are shell scripts with special inputs called at specific times by git so you can adapt them as you want, but to ask a confirmation before pushing to master you can do this:

```sh
protected_ref="refs/heads/master"
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha
do
        if [ "$remote_ref" = "$protected_ref" ]; then
        echo "Pushing to master, are you sure? (y/n)"
        read confirmation < /dev/tty
        if [ "$confirmation" != "y" ]; then
                echo >&2 "$confirmation is not 'y', cancelling push"
                exit 1
        fi
fi
done

exit 0
```

Note that when asking for user input, you have to give it a terminal to read from, as explained in the question [How to ask for user input in a Git hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495061/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-a-git-hook).

PS: GIT Version 1.8.2 or above needed for hooks to be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can `git fetch`, then `git status` will tell you if new commits have been pushed.

Comment: @Mikhail: What about you make a bash script that call git fetch and then call git pull?