# How to ask for user input in a Git hook?

Tags: git, bash, githooks

I have been trying to write a simple bash script as a `pre-push` hook, in which I check for missing test files when pushing Java code.

The problem is: the `read` command isn't waiting for user input, it proceed as if no input has been entered.

```
has_java="git diff --stat --cached origin/master | grep \"src\/main.*\.java\""
has_test="git diff --stat --cached origin/master | grep \"src\/test.*\.java\""

exit_val=0

if eval $has_java; then
    if eval $has_test; then
        :
    else
        echo "*** NO TESTS WERE FOUND WHILE PUSHING JAVA CODE ***"
        read -n1 -p "Do you want to CONTINUE pushing? [Y/n]" doit
        case $doit in  
            n|N) exit_val=1 ;; 
            y|Y) exit_val=0 ;;
            *) exit_val=0 ;;
        esac
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Don't use `eval` like this; define a shell function: `has_java () { git diff --stat ... ; }`.

Comment: Rather than make the hook interactive, consider simply requiring the user to run `git push` again with the `--no-verify` option to override the block.

Comment: I didn't get your point @chepner. With the `--no-verify` the hook would be bypassed, and that's not what I want. I need to ask the user if she would want to push code without test, at least for now. In the future it will be mandatory and the `push` will fail promptly.

Comment: The idea is the first `git push` will fail and provide an error message explaining why. Running it *again* with `--no-verify` will allow the `push` to proceed without having to do anything explicit in the hook. Keep in mind, you can't *prevent* the user from bypassing your push hook, so there's no reason not to take advantage of the user's ability to do so.

Comment: Oh, **now** I got it. And this might be, indeed, a more polished (without hacks) solution. The only downside is to add much friction to the process. My current scenario is: the team does not write tests at all, but we're starting to write a few, bit by bit. So, the first attempt is to encourage writing tests with a little annoyance. But I'll ask them to see which one they prefer. Thanks @chepner!

Comment: Oh, bugger. I just remembered another downside of using the `fail-retry` approach, we also have the `pre-push` running the unit tests, thus, if one would use `--no-verify` not only the `has tests` check would be skipped. And I guess this is a blocker.

Comment: You are trying to solve a social problem with a technical solution. If I were willing to select Y to push anyway, I would very quickly learn to just create empty Java tests files to make the test pass without any noise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151092/discussion-between-alvaro-cavalcanti-and-chepner).

Answer (score 18):

Git hooks do not use standard input. Thus, one must attach the input from the terminal: `dev/tty`.

Simply appending the terminal at the end of the command makes it work:

`read -n1 -p "Do you want to CONTINUE pushing? [Y/n]" doit < /dev/tty`

Comment: Technically, there is no guarantee that the `git` process *has* a terminal from which it can read.

Comment: Yes, but this `hook` is supposed to bet set only on the dev team's machines, which *does have* a terminal.