# Wait for interactive powershell script in git pre-commit

Tags: git, powershell

In a git project, I have a version.txt file with the following content:`1.0.0`

I have a powershell script:

```
$file = "C:\dev\bulletinboardadministration\version.txt"
$fileVersion = [version](Get-Content $file | Select -First 1)

Write-Host "Current Version: ($fileVersion)"

$majorBump = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f ($fileVersion.Major + 1), 0, 0
$minorBump = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $fileVersion.Major, ($fileVersion.Minor + 1), 0
$patchBump = "{0}.{1}.{2}" -f $fileVersion.Major, $fileVersion.Minor, ($fileVersion.Build + 1)

$newVersion = $fileVersion

function bumpVersion {
  Write-Host "Would you like to bump the current version ($fileVersion)"
  Write-Host "1. Major ($majorBump)  `n2. Minor ($minorBump) `n3. Build/Patch ($patchBump)`n4. Leave it the same"
  $menuresponse = read-host [Enter Selection]
  Switch ($menuresponse) {
    "1" {
      $script:newVersion = $majorBump
    }
    "2" {
      $script:newVersion = $minorBump
    }
    "3" {
      $script:newVersion = $patchBump
    }
    default { $script:newVersion = $fileVersion }
  }
    
}

bumpVersion

write-Host "Version will be set to $newVersion"

$newVersion | Set-Content $file
```

and I have a pre-commit git hook in my project:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe

exec powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ".\.git\hooks\pre-commit.ps1"
```

The powershell script works when run separately, but the prehook exec command doesn't wait for human interaction before ending. How can I force the git pre-commit script to wait for the human interaction in my powershell script?

Comment: Adding `< /dev/tty` worked for me. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45495062/4424236

Comment: That did it! now the version.txt file is changed and not added even though I added a `git add version.txt` at the end of my pre-commit. I'll try to figure that out next. Thanks!

Comment: Almost got it... You just add a line `git update-index --add version.txt` to it. This modifies the commit without actually adding it.